# IN operator caluse having a NULL value seems to work

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an `employee` table:

```
+--------+----------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
| emp_id | fname    | lname     | start_date | end_date | superior_emp_id | dept_id | title              | assigned_branch_id |
+--------+----------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
|      1 | Michael  | Smith     | 2005-06-22 | NULL     |            NULL |       3 | President          |                  1 |
|      2 | Susan    | Barker    | 2006-09-12 | NULL     |               1 |       3 | Vice President     |                  1 |
|      3 | Robert   | Tyler     | 2005-02-09 | NULL     |               1 |       3 | Treasurer          |                  1 |
|      4 | Susan    | Hawthorne | 2006-04-24 | NULL     |               3 |       1 | Operations Manager |                  1 |
|      5 | John     | Gooding   | 2007-11-14 | NULL     |               4 |       2 | Loan Manager       |                  1 |
|      6 | Helen    | Fleming   | 2008-03-17 | NULL     |               4 |       1 | Head Teller        |                  1 |
|      7 | Chris    | Tucker    | 2008-09-15 | NULL     |               6 |       1 | Teller             |                  1 |
|      8 | Sarah    | Parker    | 2006-12-02 | NULL     |               6 |       1 | Teller             |                  1 |
|      9 | Jane     | Grossman  | 2006-05-03 | NULL     |               6 |       1 | Teller             |                  1 |
|     10 | Paula    | Roberts   | 2006-07-27 | NULL     |               4 |       1 | Head Teller        |                  2 |
|     11 | Thomas   | Ziegler   | 2004-10-23 | NULL     |              10 |       1 | Teller             |                  2 |
|     12 | Samantha | Jameson   | 2007-01-08 | NULL     |              10 |       1 | Teller             |                  2 |
|     13 | John     | Blake     | 2004-05-11 | NULL     |               4 |       1 | Head Teller        |                  3 |
|     14 | Cindy    | Mason     | 2006-08-09 | NULL     |              13 |       1 | Teller             |                  3 |
|     15 | Frank    | Portman   | 2007-04-01 | NULL     |              13 |       1 | Teller             |                  3 |
|     16 | Theresa  | Markham   | 2005-03-15 | NULL     |               4 |       1 | Head Teller        |                  4 |
|     17 | Beth     | Fowler    | 2006-06-29 | NULL     |              16 |       1 | Teller             |                  4 |
|     18 | Rick     | Tulman    | 2006-12-12 | NULL     |              16 |       1 | Teller             |                  4 |
+--------+----------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

If I do

```
SELECT emp_id, fname, lname, title
FROM employee
WHERE emp_id IN (
    SELECT superior_emp_id
    FROM employee
);
```

I get:

```
+--------+---------+-----------+--------------------+
| emp_id | fname   | lname     | title              |
+--------+---------+-----------+--------------------+
|      1 | Michael | Smith     | President          |
|      3 | Robert  | Tyler     | Treasurer          |
|      4 | Susan   | Hawthorne | Operations Manager |
|      6 | Helen   | Fleming   | Head Teller        |
|     10 | Paula   | Roberts   | Head Teller        |
|     13 | John    | Blake     | Head Teller        |
|     16 | Theresa | Markham   | Head Teller        |
+--------+---------+-----------+--------------------+
```

There is a `NULL` value in the `superior_emp_id` column.

If the `IN` operator is equivalent to `field=val1 OR field=val2 OR field=val3 OR field=null` why does this query not fail or give some error?

Comment: Using NULL will never "given an error". NULL simply *won't match* anything - *depending on specific SQL flavor and compatibility options*; ie. "ANSI_NULLS"?. Please produce a *minimal example* where NULL does "not behave as expected". Trivially, one should be able to verify that NULL (and `=/IN`) functions *per SQL Standard* via: `SELECT CASE WHEN NULL IN (2, NULL) THEN  'bad - NULL never should not equal NULL' ELSE 'good - NULL not matched with IN' END CASE` or similar.

Comment: @user2864740 thanks. I am a little new to sql. I took your answer, "NULL simply won't match anything"  using a simple where `WHERE 'x' = NULL` and see what you mean now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works just fine.  You may be confusing `in` and `not in`.

If you run `not in`, then you will get no results.  Why?  Well, consider `1 not in (2, 3)`.  That evaluates to true.  No-brainer.

Then `2 not in (2, 3)`.  That evaluates to false.  Just as it should.

But . . . what about these two:

- `2 not in (2, 3, NULL)`
- `1 not in (2, 3, NULL)`

The first is false, because "2" is indeed in the list.  The second is . . . well, `NULL` is not a value.  It means "unknown".  So, it *could* be "1" or something else.  Hence, it evaluates to `NULL`.  And `NULL` is treated the same as false in a `where`.

You can work it out, but this does not occur with `in`.  For instance, in your case, `NULL or 1=1` evaluates to true.

For this reason, I strongly recommend always using `not exists` rather than `not in` with a subquery.  A corollary is that I recommend `exists` rather than `in`, but just so the habit of using `exists` is engrained.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Gordon. I am fairly inexperienced with SQL and don't know all the details of how it works. I thought that something like `null = 'x'` would error or something, but I was wrong.

Comment: @RobertRocha . . . Alas, there is no error or warning.  But the expression can never evaluate to true.

Comment: Since we are just checking the existence/presence of something is why you recommend `EXISTS` correct?

Comment: @RobertRocha . . . When you are using a subquery.  With an explicit list, `in` and `not in` are fine (well, unless you were in the habit of explicitly adding `NULL` to such lists).

Answer (score 0):

x=NULL predicate evaluates to UNKNOWN

With regards to the OR operator:

TRUE OR UNKNOWN  = TRUE

FALSE OR UNKNOWN = UNKNOWN (which is treated as a FALSE in the WHERE clause)

see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic